# What's the toll on memory and speed with including many dependancies

Tags: php, laravel, inversion-of-control

My Laravel controller may look something like this:

```
class TestController
{
    private $repository1;
    private $repository2;
    private $repository3;

    function __Construct(
        IRepository1 $repo1,
        IRepository2 $repo2,
        IRepository3 $repo3
    )
    {
        $this->repository1 = $repo1;
        $this->repository2 = $repo2;
        $this->repository3 = $repo3;
    }

    public function Test1()
    {
        $something = $this->repository1->GetSomething();
        // ...
    }

    ..
}
```

My bindings like this:

```
App::bind( "IRepository1", "ConcreteRepository1" );
App::bind( "IRepository2", "ConcreteRepository2" );
App::bind( "IRepository3", "ConcreteRepository3" );
```

I was worried that the more implementing class resolutions that occur on the construct, the slower the program is going to be on runtime, regardless of the fact that the controller method `Test1` (which may be the only page the user loads) is the ONLY method that uses `$this->repository1`... so why resolve all dependencies just for this one method?

**Question**
So how do you go above giving dependancies to just a single method? rather than everytime the controller is used, it goes and fetches every implementing class regardless of the user only ever navigating to Test1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of any speed - if you have too many dependencies in your class or controller - it is usually a good sign that the class/controller is doing too much - and you should refactor into smaller classes/controllers.

This would not only solve your concern of speed/memory - but would clean up your code, which is more important in this scenario (as the speed/memory is likely to be negligible).

> So how do you go above giving dependancies to just a single method? rather than everytime the controller is used, it goes and fetches every implementing class regalrdless of the user only every navigating to Test1?

The short answer is your dont (cant) - because the dependencies are resolved when you construct the class.

The longer answer is that once you feel you have too many dependencies that it might be causing speed issues - then you should refactor your code and split the class into smaller classes. This will improve your code readability and maintainability

Comment: Sorry, this is just a question, not a representation of my real code. But as a comeback to your question, an AuthorisationController may need to Authorise with an external API, UserRepository to check if user exists, SessionRepository etc... but actually one of the functions may need all of them, and one may not. i had wondered if it was indeed possible to give function dependancies for such cases.

Comment: Yeah - but thats my point - unless you have hundreds of dependencies - you will not notice any speed changes. And you should never had hundreds of dependencies - so therefore its not a problem.

Comment: Do you have any proof of this, that'd be awesome! then i don't have to get the proof for my company, it's already done :D... Obviously any dependancies defined in the controller will take a big narly dump on your memory so you better god damn be using the stuff it's declaring.

Comment: If you need "proof"- just run a loop 10000 times creating objects with/without dependancies. But it doesnt matter - because you should be refactoring anyway - so either way its a non-issue.